# How to pass multiple onChange form data from child to parent element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frameworks

I am trying to print real-time user input from input tags by the user. I am even getting multiple user inputs from the child element to the parent element as a form of an object using useState. But whenever the user tries to fill the second input field, then the first input is re-render and it's replaced by the primary state which is an empty string.
code:-
Child Element

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");

  let userData = {
    name: "",
    age: ""
  };
  const nameChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
    userData.name = e.target.value;
  };

  const ageChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setAge(e.target.value);
    userData.age = e.target.value;
  };

  const formOnChageHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.getData(userData);
  };
  const fromOnSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onChange={formOnChageHandler} onSubmit={fromOnSubmitHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          value={name}
          onChange={nameChangeHandler}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
        <input
          id="age"
          placeholder="Enter Age"
          value={age}
          onChange={ageChangeHandler}
        />
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Child;
```

Parent Element

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./components/Child";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  let userData = (data) => {
    setName(data.name);
    setAge(data.age);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Child getData={userData} />
      <h1>Your name is:{name}</h1>
      <h1>Your age is:{age}</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

code sandbox Link- https://codesandbox.io/s/from-traversing-child-to-parent-to-another-child-ynwyqd?file=/src/App.js:0-441

How I can get both data being reflected by using onChange from child to parent element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you accumulate the user data in one `state`.
Like this.

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    age: null
  });
```

And put the `state` on the parent and pass as props, also just have one `handleChange` function to update both the `name` and `age` by the `input` `id`

Child.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = ({ user, setUser }) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUser((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  const formOnChageHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  const fromOnSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onChange={formOnChageHandler} onSubmit={fromOnSubmitHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          value={user.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
        <input
          id="age"
          placeholder="Enter Age"
          value={user.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Child;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./components/Child";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    age: null
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Child user={user} setUser={setUser} />
      <h1>Your name is:{user.name}</h1>
      <h1>Your age is:{user.age}</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/from-traversing-child-to-parent-to-another-child-forked-qggrk9)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This code is very easy to grasp. Now my doubt is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the child component as below,

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");

  let userData = {
    name: name,  // the value "name" comes for the local state will be listen to the onChange event every time
    age: age  // same applies here as well
  };
  const nameChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
    
  };

  const ageChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setAge(e.target.value);

  };

  const formOnChageHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.getData(userData);
  };
  const fromOnSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form  onSubmit={fromOnSubmitHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          value={name}
          onChange={nameChangeHandler}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
        <input
          id="age"
          placeholder="Enter Age"
          value={age}
          onChange={ageChangeHandler}
        />
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Child;
```

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help. Now my doubt has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

just use simple one state to manage data. just take a look below example component created from your child component.

1. we simply use `single object` state.
2. use `name` prop as key to store value in state.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  
  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    };

  const formOnChageHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.getData(userData);
  };
  const fromOnSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
 
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onChange={formOnChageHandler} onSubmit={fromOnSubmitHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          value={name}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="name"
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
        <input
          id="age"
          placeholder="Enter Age"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="age"
        />
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Child;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This code is very understandable. Thank you for the help. Can I use the useContext to this as a provider in the parent element?

Comment: @isuro there is no useContext in your parent element.

Answer (score 1):

it happens because you dont watch to the state, try this:

Child.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");

  let userData = {
    name,
    age
  };
  const nameChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
    userData.name = e.target.value;
  };

  const ageChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setAge(e.target.value);
    userData.age = e.target.value;
  };

  const formOnChageHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.getData(userData);
  };
  const fromOnSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onChange={formOnChageHandler} onSubmit={fromOnSubmitHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          value={name}
          onChange={nameChangeHandler}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
        <input
          id="age"
          placeholder="Enter Age"
          value={age}
          onChange={ageChangeHandler}
        />
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help. It cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i check in codesandbox and it works:

In App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./components/Child";

    function App() {
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [age, setAge] = useState("");
    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Child name={name} age={age} setName={setName} setAge={setAge} />
          <h1>Your name is:{name}</h1>
          <h1>Your age is:{age}</h1>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

In Child.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = ({ name, age, setName, setAge }) => {
  const nameChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const ageChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setAge(e.target.value);
  };

  const fromOnSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={fromOnSubmitHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          value={name}
          onChange={nameChangeHandler}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
        <input
          id="age"
          placeholder="Enter Age"
          value={age}
          onChange={ageChangeHandler}
        />
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Child;
```

If you want to improve your code, you can research and use state management like: redux, zustand, react context,...

Hope it useful for you.